# Can't use npm install after I updated the version of all nestjs dependencies in my package.json

Tags: npm, nestjs, npm-install, typeorm

I have created a new nestjs project and installed several additional standard packages. In the console it said that the packages are outdated and there are 7 red vulnerabilities.

The suggested command `npm audit fix --force` did't help - there were still 4 red vulnerabilities after that.
I found a command that updates my packages to the latest versions:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

Now I can't use `npm install`:

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.4
npm ERR! Found: typeorm@0.3.6
npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
npm ERR!   typeorm@"^0.3.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typeorm@"^0.2.34" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm ERR!   @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typeorm@0.2.45
npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
npm ERR!   peer typeorm@"^0.2.34" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm ERR!     @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I deleted `node_modules` as well as the `package-lock.json` and then forced the installation with `npm install --force`. But I get again the message about severity vulnerabilities:

```
npm install --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.4
npm WARN Found: typeorm@0.3.6
npm WARN node_modules/typeorm
npm WARN   typeorm@"^0.3.6" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typeorm@"^0.2.34" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.4
npm WARN node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm WARN   @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.4" from the root project
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: typeorm@0.2.45
npm WARN node_modules/typeorm
npm WARN   peer typeorm@"^0.2.34" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
npm WARN     @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.0.4" from the root project

added 823 packages, and audited 824 packages in 29s

84 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

7 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

I am going in circles and do not understand how to solve the problem. And especially which version I need to use that has no red security issues?

My `package.json` file now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.4.5",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.4.5",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.4.5",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.4",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.8",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.2.6",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.11",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.4.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Why do I get an indication that I am using typeorm@"^0.2.34" even though my `package.json` file specifies a newer version "**typeorm**": "**^0.3.6**"? This is also the latest version at the moment.

**PS:** If I change the typorm version back to 0.2.34 or 0.2, I can use `npm install` again but I get the red "7 high severity vulnerabilities" message.

Comment: since you're using `@nestjs/typeorm` 8, you should use `typeorm@0.2`. https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/pull/1233

Comment: Then I get the following red message again: "7 high severity vulnerabilities".  What combination of versions of Nestjs and TypORM and other packages do I need to use so I don't get this message about severity vulnerabilities?

Comment: How dangerous is it to ignore these issues and what should I do if "npm audit fix --force" can't fix them automatically? I am not yet able to understand the developers' code or fix the bugs myself, as my programming skills are not sufficient for that.

Comment: read this: [npm audit: Broken by Design](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me. Using `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` seems to fix the issue however vulnerabilities remains.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just got the some problem as yours it's because the `nest and npm` commands getting blocked so try to allow it from Windows PowerShell by following these steps [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-ps1-can-not-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-sys/)

Comment: Hi, I use Ubuntu. I was able to fix the problem by changing back to version 0.2, but I still have red warnings due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

update to the latest npm version by running this command
npm i -g npm@latest